# UITableViewCell content not filling up whole cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to implement custom UITableViewCells in my app. I want to add a UIScrollView with several subviews to each UITableViewCell and enable horizontal scrolling. I was mostly able to do it except with the height and grouping. Check out my code and screenshot below. I am not able to change the UIScrollView's height to a number greater than 44 points.

How can I add a UIScrollView, with a height greater than 44, to my custom UITableViewCell?

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Home Scroll Cell";
    homeScrollCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[homeScrollCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    NSLog(@"Cell: %f", cell.bounds.size.height);




    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100.0;
}

@end
```

UITableCell class

```
#import "homeScrollCell.h"

@implementation homeScrollCell

//- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
//{
//
//}

-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 100)];
        NSInteger viewcount= 3;
        for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++) {

            CGFloat x = i * self.bounds.size.width;
            HomeTodayView *view = [[HomeTodayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,self.bounds.size.width, self .bounds.size.height)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

            [scrollView addSubview:view];

        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width *viewcount, 100);
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.bounces = NO;
        [self addSubview:scrollView];


        NSLog(@"Height: %f", self.bounds.size.height);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  //  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Set the UIScrollView's frame to be the tableViewCell's bounds (or frame, I never remember off the top of my head):

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
```

Then set it's height to autoResize

```
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

You shouldn't have to manually change the cell's height within the actual cell. The height should all be managed in your TableViewController's delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it! I needed to autoresize the subview too, so it fits.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting frame of the cell

Have you tried checking in line where you init the HomeTodayView what is the return value of self.bounds.size.height?

Maybe you could make another initializer for your cell with another parameter - frame? Start it like this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.frame = frame;

        /* rest of the init method you already have goes here */
```

Basically, just add self.frame = frame; at the start of the 'if'.

Comment: 2013-07-24 16:06:34.842 EDM[11833:c07] Height: 44.000000
2013-07-24 16:06:34.843 EDM[11833:c07] Cell: 44.000000
2013-07-24 16:06:34.844 EDM[11833:c07] Height: 44.000000
2013-07-24 16:06:34.845 EDM[11833:c07] Cell: 44.000000

Here is the NSLog I do, height is from Cell class, Cell is from View Controller

Comment: in your initWithStyle(...) method frame isn't set to what you want, so you could try making another init method -(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier frame:(CGRect)frame,     where you set the frame of the cell

Comment: And how should I use the frame parameter?

Comment: Edited my answer with setting the frame

Answer (score 0):

initial size of UItableViewcell is 44.0f You Check it after calling

```
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

You need to make you scrollView height stretchable.

```
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

It helps for me.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VXvEwYR.png It increased the size of the scroll view, but it did not fill it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
        CGFloat x = i * self.bounds.size.width;
        HomeTodayView *view = [[HomeTodayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,self.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Or replace your whole code with

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width,self.bounds.size.height)];
        [scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        NSInteger viewcount= 3;

        for(int i = 0; i< viewcount; i++)
        {
            CGFloat x = i * self.bounds.size.width;

            HomeTodayView *view = [[HomeTodayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,self.bounds.size.width,scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

            [scrollView addSubview:view];
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width *viewcount, 100);
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.bounces = NO;
        [self addSubview:scrollView];


        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Even if u didn't understand whats the problem was, then have a look at following lines

Your problem got here

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 100)];
```

You are setting scrollView height to constant value so scrollView does not resize when HeightForRowAtIndex path resizes height of cell.

And setting `[scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];` will allow scrollView to resize when its container resizes and also allows its contents to be resized.

[Check this Demo](http://ge.tt/5nR0nmm/v/0)

Comment: Thanks man, my internet was going up and down and I didn't see your answer!Much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, it still limits it to the 44. Here is the screenshot. I set the HeightForRow to 500 and added red as scrollview background.

http://i.imgur.com/tCgac71.png

Comment: need to send u demo right? @user2067051 check demo uploaded in answer