# how to set the size of UIViews in uitableviewcell custom cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, customization

I have a UIButton in Custom Cell of UITableView on Drag of that button i have to open a another view in cell which is in Custom cell initially in the right most corner of the cell...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 RecentCell *cell = (RecentCell*)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecentCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }

    [cell.TestButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ViewMovedTouchDragInside:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

return cell;

}
```

And this method is called when button is dragged

```
- (IBAction) ViewMovedTouchDragInside:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UIControl *control = sender;

    UITouch *t = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint pPrev = [t previousLocationInView:control];
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:control];

    CGPoint center = control.center;
    center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
    RecentCell * swipedCell = (RecentCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:hitIndex];
       //Drag Button on left hand side
        if (control.frame.origin.x<0) {


        swipedCell.MessageView.Frame=CGRectMake(320.0+control.frame.origin.x,0,control.frame.origin.x,swipedCell.MessageView.frame.size.height);

       NSLog(@"*****%f*****%f****%f****%f",swipedCell.MessageView.frame.origin.x,swipedCell.MessageView.frame.origin.y,swipedCell.MessageView.frame.size.width,swipedCell.MessageView.frame.size.height);
            }
            else{
               swipedCell.CallImage.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0,control.frame.origin.x,cell.CallImage.frame.size .height);
            }
        }
```

Orange Image is working properly But Blue Image view frame is getting zero...

Please suggesest me how can I do this...

[image]

Comment: check this demo http://stackoverflow.com/a/17836383/1305001

Comment: keep your object in scrollView instead and just drag right and left